# Migrating from bot framework V4 preview to V4 stable(4.0.8)

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service

I have developed bot application using Microsoft bot framework V4 preview(4.0.1 Preview) 
Now i want to migrate to new stable version (4.0.8)

Can anyone tell me what are the breaking changes and how to fix those..

Comment: Any reason to downvote...??

Comment: I have updated the project with the latest packages and i see errors everywhere,
1. Previously i was using DialogContainer to modularize my bot logic, i cannnot find the same class in latest version 
2. Getting conversation state has completely changed i think
I am looking for complete changes made from preview to stable version and what are the replacement for the changes like .. what supposed to be used instead of DialogContainer

Answer (score 1):

The downvotes are probably because this is a very broad question, as the framework went through some pretty significant changes from Preview to Stable. For example, if I'm not mistaken, what you call DialogContainer is probably ComponentDialog now. No one's going to be able to say what the breaking changes are, because they broke in different places for different bots, depending on the the bot's code. If you attempt to upgrade to 4.0.8 and run into errors, you can post those errors and get better assistance in solving each one.

Comment: You are right, but the breaking changes are so much in numbers that if i post separate question for each of the errors it will take me days to do so, I think this supposed to be done by microsoft, to publish breaking changes and alternative to fix those, because as i can see there many , and tracing each error and finding fix for the error is a very tedious job as there are very few resources are available.